# глобальная переменная procces is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

В бэк-енд разработке я новичок и не могу понять почему мой вебпак не может запустить корневой серверный файл из за того что не обнаружена переменная process (полное имя process.env.MONGODB_URI). Подскажите почему так (она объявлена в файле .env и в тому же коневом серверном файле я подключал плагин `require('dotenv').config();`)

код ее использование

```
const url = procces.env.MONGODB_URI ||
     `mongodb://${config.db.host}:${config.db.port}/${config.db.name}`;
```

Comment: Покажите ошибку

Comment: var url = procces.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://' + _configIndexJson2['default'].db.host + ':' + _configIndexJson2['default'].db.port + '/' + _configIndexJson2['default'].db.name;
          ^

ReferenceError: procces is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:/projects/app_note/app/server/utils/dataBaseUtils.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30) ....

Comment: у вас опечатка в переменной. Правильно process

Comment: спасибо! спустя много часов поиска проблемы в сборке, она нашлась у синтаксисе(